# How to define an alternative database adapter config file in Apigility?

Tags: zend-framework2, configuration-files, application-settings, laminas-api-tools

In an Apigility driven Zend Framework 2 application wenn a database adapter is created (over the Apigility Admin UI), its settings by default get saved in `/config/autoload/global.php`

```
return array(
    'db' => array(
        'adapters' => array(
            ...
            'DbAdapter_FooBar' => array(),
            ...
        ),
    ),
    ...
);
```

and in `/config/autoload/local.php`

```
return array(
    'db' => array(
        'adapters' => array(
            ...
            'DbAdapter_FooBar' => array(
                'charset' => 'UTF-8',
                'database' => 'asdf',
                'driver' => 'PDO_Mysql',
                'hostname' => 'asdf',
                'username' => 'asdf',
                'password' => 'asdf',
                'port' => '1234',
                'driver_options' => array(
                    1002 => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\'',
                ),
            ),
            ...
        ),
    ),
    ...
);
```

In the application I'm working on the config files structure differs from the ZF2 standard, e.g. there are separate config files for the database settings: `/config/autoload/mydb.global.php` and `/config/autoload/mydb.local.php`.

**(How) Can Apigility be configured in the way, that the database adapters settings get stored in custom config files? How/where to set these files?**

Answer (score 0):

Configuration for various components can be provided in multiple places, but all configuration is merged recursively into one large configuration file by the `Zend\Stdlib\ArrayUtils::merge()` method. Because configurations are merged recursively, the order that they are added to the merged configuration array is really important to avoid unexpected overwriting.

**Configurations are merged in the following order:**

- The `array` returned by the module’s `getConfig()` method
- `config/autoload/*.global.php` — global autoload files
- `config/autoload/*.local.php` — local autoload files
- The methods described by the Feature interface — `get*Config()`